# Combine dual Sync/Async interface implementations

Tags: c#, async-await

I have duplicate interface method(s) for Sync and Async versions.  Each method is ~30 lines long and does exactly the same thing.  Except in the middle where one awaits an Async method, but the other calls a Synchronous method.

My current pattern just combines them with a boolean I refer to as the "DoAsync" pattern, though I don't remember where I saw it some years ago.

Being that the implementation guarantees no async stuff is happening (No working with Tasks), does that change the understood logic of using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` over `.Result`?  Is it right to assume calling the private method synchronously would lose all accepted concerns of "calling async method synchronously" because of the style of implementation?  What else changes?  Or, what other patterns are common to combine async and sync methods that do exactly the same thing?

This is the pattern I'm talking about:

```
public class MyImplementation : IDoSomething {

    public async Task DoSomethingAsync(object input)
        => await DoSomethingInternally(input);

    public void DoSomething(object input)
        => DoSomethingInternally(input, false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    private async Task DoSomethingInternally(object input, bool runSynchronously = false) {
        //a dozen other lines of code
        object somethingINeed;
        if (runSynchronously) somethingINeed = GetSomething(input, lol);
        else somethingINeed = await GetSomethingAsync(input, lol);
        //a dozen other lines of code
    }
}
```

Comment: Arguably you shouldn't have so many lines of code in a single function anyway, so @AlexanderPetrov is correct, just abstract them out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't remember where I saw it some years ago.

Probably from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#the-flag-argument-hack) of mine. I was introduced to the pattern by Stephen Toub when he did a technical review of that article.

> Being that the implementation guarantees no async stuff is happening (No working with Tasks), does that change the understood logic of using GetAwaiter().GetResult() over .Result?

`GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - although verbose - is the accepted pattern. This is because of how exceptions are handled; `Result` will wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`.

> Is it right to assume calling the private method synchronously would lose all accepted concerns of "calling async method synchronously" because of the style of implementation? What else changes?

Yes. The way the pattern works is that if `runSynchronously` is `true`, then it *must* return a completed task. Since the task is already completed, it is safe to block on without any chance of deadlocks. Technically, "block" isn't really the right word, since the task is complete; the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is just extracting the result (return value or exception) from the task.

> Or, what other patterns are common to combine async and sync methods that do exactly the same thing?

One update to my article is that `ValueTask<T>` is now available, which means there's no need to allocate a `Task<T>` for the synchronous path.

Also, Stephen Toub just published a blog post a few weeks ago that mentions [a further improvement to the pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance_improvements_in_net_7/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#networking:%7E:text=One%20final%20change%20related%20to%20reading%20and%20writing%20performance). There's a kind of trick you can do; I don't think it has a name yet, but I think of it as "generic code generation", since logically it's similar to template code generation in C++. The idea is that you have a *value* type that implements an interface, and by constraining a generic argument to that interface, the compiler will generate different code for each generic argument (they're different because they're value types). Further, due to the constraint and lack of inheritance, the resulting IL has an extremely high chance of being well-optimized (i.e., inlined) by the JIT compiler.

It might be easier to explain with an example than with words:

```
interface IDoGetSomething
{
  ValueTask<object> DoGetSomethingAsync(object input, Lol lol);
}

struct SyncDoGetSomething : IDoGetSomething
{
  public ValueTask<object> DoGetSomethingAsync(object input, Lol lol) =>
      new(GetSomething(input, lol));
}

struct AsyncDoGetSomething : IDoGetSomething
{
  public async ValueTask<object> DoGetSomethingAsync(object input, Lol lol) =>
      await GetSomethingAsync(input, lol);
}
```

The above is the generic code generation pattern for the parts of `DoSomethingInternally` that are different between sync and async code. `DoSomethingInternally` then participates in the generic code generation like this:

```
private async Task DoSomethingInternally<TDoGetSomething>(object input)
    where TDoGetSomething : IDoGetSomething
{
  //a dozen other lines of code
  object somethingINeed = await default(TDoGetSomething).DoGetSomethingAsync(input, lol);
  //a dozen other lines of code
}
```

And is exposed as such:

```
public Task DoSomethingAsync(object input)
    => DoSomethingInternally<AsyncDoGetSomething>(input);

public void DoSomething(object input)
    => DoSomethingInternally<SyncDoGetSomething>(input).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

And that's the end of the pattern. Perhaps a bit more verbose, but it does provide one nice benefit: all the synchronous/asynchronous differences are in a separate place (`IDoGetSomething` and its implementations) instead of being scattered through your implementation method.

Side note: Since this is using generic code generation, there will be *two* separate `DoSomethingInternally` methods generated, one bound to `AsyncDoGetSomething` and the other bound to `SyncDoGetSomething`. Previously there would only be one method that took a `bool` (runtime) parameter.

C# 11 introduces static interface methods, so generic code generation becomes even nicer, avoiding the awkward `default(T)` constructs:

```
interface IDoGetSomething
{
  static abstract ValueTask<object> DoGetSomethingAsync(object input, Lol lol);
}

struct SyncDoGetSomething : IDoGetSomething
{
  public static ValueTask<object> DoGetSomethingAsync(object input, Lol lol) =>
      new(GetSomething(input, lol));
}

struct AsyncDoGetSomething : IDoGetSomething
{
  public static async ValueTask<object> DoGetSomethingAsync(object input, Lol lol) =>
      await GetSomethingAsync(input, lol);
}

private async Task DoSomethingInternally<TDoGetSomething>(object input)
    where TDoGetSomething : IDoGetSomething
{
  //a dozen other lines of code
  object somethingINeed = await TDoGetSomething.DoGetSomethingAsync(input, lol);
  //a dozen other lines of code
}

// (the rest is unchanged)
public Task DoSomethingAsync(object input)
    => DoSomethingInternally<AsyncDoGetSomething>(input);

public void DoSomething(object input)
    => DoSomethingInternally<SyncDoGetSomething>(input).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# methods are colored

Unfortunately C# doesn't have any abstractions for *how* a method is called. C# methods are [colored](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) and there's no getting around that.

One alternative is to only have an `async` implementation instead of both `async` and non-`async`. In your case you would throw away the `public void DoSomething(object input)` method (and move the body of the `xyzInternally` method to the async method).

Unfortunately that leads to an annoying condition where you have to use async/await all the way up the call stack from your async method. It's called "async cancer" and is caused by the fact that C# methods are colored.

---

I might be missing the big picture. If so, then please provide a couple more examples so I can see the same pattern that you're seeing.

---

P.S. `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is essentially the same as `Task.Result`. Yes there's a difference in how exceptions come through, but both can easily lead to deadlock (and other issues). For example: can you guarantee that `await GetSomethingAsync(input, lol)` will *never* reenter `DoSomethingInternally`?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync(object input)
{
    var lol = FirstDozenLinesWrapperMethod();
    await GetSomethingAsync(input, lol);
    LastDozenLinesWrapperMethod();
}

public void DoSomething(object input)
{
    var lol = FirstDozenLinesWrapperMethod();
    GetSomething(input, lol);
    LastDozenLinesWrapperMethod();
}
```